# Drupal 7 CKEditor-CKFinder remove "Browse Server"

Tags: wysiwyg

I have a multi-domain site setup with domain access module. In each domain users are allowed to post their own contents with media upload settings. I am using CKEditor and CKFinder together.

Now, I want to disable the "Browse Server" Button but the local Browse button will be there.

I am unable to find the settings(which I think not in Drupal admin) or the code to edit to fixup this. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610041/ckeditor-with-ckfinder-disable-filebrowser-keep-upload-functionality
This one didn't helped my either.
Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

Well I have found that patch solution. So just answering my own question. 
In sites/all/modules/ckeditor/includes/ckeditor.lib.inc file,

There is a section as

```
if (user_access('allow CKFinder file uploads')) {
                $ckfinder_full_path = $host . ckfinder_path();
                //$settings['filebrowserBrowseUrl'] = $ckfinder_full_path . '/ckfinder.html?id=' . $profile_name;
                //$settings['filebrowserImageBrowseUrl'] = $ckfinder_full_path . '/ckfinder.html?Type=Images&id=' . $profile_name;
                //$settings['filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl'] = $ckfinder_full_path . '/ckfinder.html?Type=Flash&id=' . $profile_name;
                $settings['filebrowserBrowseUrl'] = '';
                $settings['filebrowserImageBrowseUrl'] = '';
                $settings['filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl'] = '';
                $settings['filebrowserUploadUrl'] = $ckfinder_full_path . '/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&id=' . $profile_name;
                $settings['filebrowserImageUploadUrl'] = $ckfinder_full_path . '/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&id=' . $profile_name;
                $settings['filebrowserFlashUploadUrl'] = $ckfinder_full_path . '/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash&id=' . $profile_name;
            }
```

So I commented the actual filebrowserBrowseUrl, filebrowserImageBrowseUrl & filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl settings and made those as blank. That did the trick.

Comment: Is there no alternative without hacking the code?

Comment: as of now I haven't. :(